# how to dynamically change app.scss value in ember js

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I have a situation where the api is providing me with a colour and  the colour of some parts of the site should be based on the colour provided by the api, right now the value is hard coded in app.scss file, is there a way where i can dynamically change the value of it?

consider this case, i am on user route, and user model is providing me with a colour yellow, now how do i apply this colour to the body tag, the footer etc?
and there are other addons whose colors needs to be changed,
right now i have hard coded the color of the addon in app.scss

is there a way i can change the color of app.scss based on the color supplied by the api?

Comment: For this case, is setting a style tag just by JS not easier? So let's say in your setupController hook you just grab the element and add a style (e.g. `document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";`).

Answer (score 3):

If you don't need to support IE, you could use [CSS Variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables), ([caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables)) and change their values with JavaScript.

In your CSS, set `--variable-name: value` in document root (so it's global).
Then use it in other places with `var(--variable-name)`:

```css
:root {
  --main-bg-color: red;  
}

#div1 {
  background-color: var(--main-bg-color);
  padding: 5px;  
}
```

and in JavaScript:

```js
changeColor(newColor) {
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--main-bg-color', newColor);
}
```

[Here is an example with ember-twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/1404058f109df82a40e95a7e6955f229?openFiles=styles.app.css%2C)

Answer (score 1):

Ember-cli compiles `app.scss` into `css` during the build process and you can not affect it when application is running.

If colors are pre-defined (i.e. user can choose color scheme from list), you can create pre-defined css-classes for `body` tag and then just change css-class of `body` element.

You can use a following component to change css-class of `body` tag

```
import $ from 'jquery';

import Component from '@ember/component';

export default Component.extend({
  didReceiveAttrs() {
    const oldClass = this._oldBodyClass;
    if (typeof oldClass === 'string') {
      $('body').removeClass(oldClass);
    }
    const bodyClass = this.bodyClass;
    if (bodyClass) {
      $('body').addClass(bodyClass);
      this.set('_oldBodyClass', bodyClass);
    }
  },
  willDestroyElement() {
    const bodyClass = this.bodyClass;
    if (bodyClass) {
      $('body').removeClass(bodyClass);
    }
  },
});
```

Somewhere in template (probably application):

```
{{body-class bodyClass=(user.bodyClass)}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this [addon](https://github.com/luxferresum/ember-css-vars) will help you. You can create computed property which depends of your api respond with color and then apply it to the html tag as in example.